# Why can't I get this video to play on my website using Vide package?

Tags: html, video

I'm using the [**Vide**](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide) plugin to display a video on my website.
But it is not working for me.

Here is what's in my HTML:

```
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"
  data-vide-bg="dist/media/light" data-vide-options="loop: false, muted: false, position: 0% 0%">
</div>
```

Here is (part of) my app's directory structure. It's the part that contains the video:

[image]

According to the instructions I see, I'm doing everything right. The video should appear on my website. However it doesn't. And here is the error I see in the console window in Google Chrome:

[image]

Why am I getting this error & why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery before you load vide?

Comment: Alan, yes. That was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alan's suggestion was correct.

I had the line

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

after

```
<script src="bower_components/vide/dist/jquery.vide.js"></script>`
```

When I reversed their order, the error disappeared.

Comment: You should just delete your question then

Comment: Why? What if someone else has the same question I had? Shouldn't they be able to see this solution?

Comment: Because there are thousands of questions like this already floating around SO. Not to mention that there are  no keywords or phrases in your question or your posted answer that would lead someone with the same issue to find your question. This is precisely why we have the close reason *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."*