# Why am I getting jQuery error "url.indexOf is not a function" while using Vide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

This question is a follow-up to the one I posted earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353287/why-cant-i-get-this-video-to-play-on-my-website-using-vide-package) about using the Web front-end plugin Vide to play background videos.

Now, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

What is the cause of this? How can I fix it?
I seems to be trying to to an `indexOf()` on the variable `url` and its failing. But why? In my code I have not defined any such variable `url`. So is there a bug in the Vide plugin? How can I trouble-shoot this??

This is how I'm using this plugin in my HTML:

```
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"
  data-vide-bg="dist/media/light" data-vide-options="loop: false, muted: false, position: 0% 0%">
</div>

<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/vide/dist/jquery.vide.js"></script>
```

Comment: First glance suggests a bug, or improper usage. (Plugins vary as to the level of warnings they raise, meaning it can be hard to spot when your usage is wrong.) It seems something `url`, wherever it's defined, is not a string or array, i.e. does not have a method `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a known issue on the GitHub repo.

https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide/issues/183